# Отследить переключения на следующий этап wp contact form 7 multi step

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form7

У меня на сайте c движком WordPress есть плагин - contact form 7 multi step, и после изменения шага формы мне надо делать скролл вверх. Как мне отследить изменения шага?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При новом шаге делается скролл, но я так и не нашёл, как это можно реализовать.

Я думаю, что это можно сделать через отслеживание события на изменения шага через jquery, но я так и не нашёл, как это вызывается и есть ли вообще.

Comment: Если API плагина не предусматривает события при изменении шага, то можно использовать [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) для отслеживания изменений классов элементов при их изменении. Исправьте ошибки в вопросе.

Comment: В этом плагине  каждый шаг-отдельная страница. И урд шага прописывается в форме. Ну так надо попробовать создать якоря на странице. Пробовал это делать?

Comment: Хотя судя по предыдущему твоему вопросу тебе как раз нужно убрать скролл, а не дёргать страницу туда-сюда. И судя по всему ты ло сих пор не заглянул в конструктор форм...

Comment: там проблема была не в скроле, просто форма уменшалась а скрол пользователя был на месте

Comment: и выходила такая ситуация как буд-то сайт скролился